Ansible role: useradd causes an "unreachable" error in the following tasks
i'm writing an ansible role that needs to create a new user
all the tasks before
- name: Creazione utente
  user:
    name: oper1
    state: present

are working without any problem, any task following this one causes
fatal: [default]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": 
   "Failed to create temporary directory. In some cases, you may have been able to authenticate and did not have permissions on the target directory. Consider changing the remote tmp path in ansible.cfg to a path rooted in \"/tmp\", for more error information use -vvv.
    Failed command was:
    ( umask 77 &&
      mkdir -p \"` echo /home/**oper1**/.ansible/tmp `\" &&
      mkdir \"` echo /home/oper1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1730129273.9595325-2556995-78298725368745 `\" && 
      echo ansible-tmp-1730129273.9595325-2556995-78298725368745=\"`
      echo /home/oper1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1730129273.9595325-2556995-78298725368745 `\" ), 
       exited with result 1", "unreachable": true}

in few words it's like ansible want to start to use the new user to launch the following tasks
some workaround i've tryed:

launch the useradd in an script and create the .ansible temp folder in the same script (note: the error is in the task following the 'useradd' one)
use a reset ssh connection task

thanks in advance if someone can help me

The main reason is: after creating the user, ansible tries to execute some tasks using the new created user's env, but new user doesn't have required permissions.
I use as following while creating new user. It dynamically adapts to system configs and handles edge cases very well:
---
- name: Get Existing Groups
  getent:
    database: group

- name: Check if user already exists
  ansible.builtin.shell: |
    id -u {{ user_name }}
  register: user_check
  ignore_errors: yes

- name: Fail if user already exists
  ansible.builtin.fail:
    msg: "User '{{ user_name }}' already exists."
  when: user_check.rc == 0

- name: Create new user
  ansible.builtin.user:
    name: "{{ user_name }}"
    shell: /bin/bash
    createhome: yes
    groups: "{{ ['sudo', 'adm', 'wheel'] | intersect(ansible_facts['getent_group'] | list) }}"
    password: "{{ ansible_become_password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    update_password: on_create
  become: true
  become_user: root
  when: user_check.rc != 0

